# How can I separate a text object into meshes?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, text-object

What I need Is to find a way to separate a text object in letters, like the Animation Nodes's Separate text object node would do.
All of this should be doable with a code.

I could convert the text into a mesh and separate by loose parts but this would create two different meshes for letters that are made up by two or more pieces, like for example the "i".

Some images to explain what I'm trying to achieve:

This is the text:
[image: This is the text:]

Using the way eplained above:

[image: This is the results:]

> As you can see, the I letter is made up by two pieces instead of one.

Using this node **(Animation Nodes by Jacques Lucke):**
[image: Separate Text Objects]

I got this results:

[image: Results]

> As you can see the letter "i" is only one letter

Is there a way to do this with a script?

Comment: Is there any reason that you've not simply looked at the code for Animation Nodes to see how it's done there?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't undestrand

Comment: Either first split into individual character text objects (offsetting with kerning prolly not fun though) or sort the text mesh faces by vertical axis face median coordinate and start splitting them by grabbing along any faces that have horizontal median coordinate between character's vertices min and max horizontal values?